# Can we put 'a' in front of uncountable nouns?

Tags: indefinite-article, countability

Can we put 'a' in front of uncountable nouns like love, hate, peace?

Comment: There seems to be a common belief that you can't use articles with abstract nouns, but it's not true.  Really *uncountable* nouns don't take articles or quantifiers (like "a sand" or "one ice") but *love, hate* and *peace* are not uncountable nouns.  You can have *a great love* or *an intense hate* or *an uneasy peace*.

Answer (score 1):

If you modify a noun with an article (the, a, an), it basically alters the meaning from general to specific.

> "Book" means "book as a general entity.
>
> "A book" means "one book out of several"
>
> "The book" means "a specific example of book as a general entity"

In the case of the non-countable nouns you've listed above, the inclusion of an article conveys the exact same idea.

> "Love" means "love as a general concept"
>
> "A love" means "one example of the concept of love"
>
> "The love" means "a specific example of the concept of love"

Example

**"Peace is worth fighting for"**
This is a general statement about "peace".

**"A peace that is worth fighting for"**
This statement suggests that the speaker has a specific view of what he considers peace.  He is saying, "Of all the different types or interpretations of peace there are, I think this one is worth fighting for.

In the case

Comment: In the case ... what? Is there a difference between _altering_ and _basically altering?_ How does a _general_ entity differ from an _entity?_ Similarly, how does a _general_ concept differ from a _concept?_